# ST10F269Z2T3 abnormal Input Logic Levels

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, input, logic-level, st

We are using a ST10F269Z2T3 Microcontroller [(Datasheet)](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/99/3b/0f/d2/28/ab/4f/8e/CD00152495.pdf/files/CD00152495.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00152495.pdf) in one of our old Designs. Among other things, the ST10 monitors the functionality of external devices using Standard logic Inputs. Eg.: Input is high --> device connected and working, Input is low --> device is defective or not connected.

While doing some tests i discovered that the ST10 has abnormal input voltage levels for detecting high and low. The datasheet states (see Table 44 on page 161) that a low input ranges from -0.5V to 0.9V and a high input is detected from 1.9V to 5.5V (when supplied with 5V). The ST10 also has the functionality of activating so called "special thresholds" for Inputs (see Table 44 on lage 161 again). If special thresholds are activated a low input would range from -0.5V to 2V and a high input would range from 3V to 5.5V (again when supplied with 5V). While testing i discovered though, that the Controller detects a low from 1.38V downwards and a high from 1.53V upwards which is definitely neither near the standard TTL input levels nor the "special threshold" input levels.

The measurements where conducted with multiple boards to rule out a defective IC, showing the same results. Also there was no external circuitry connected to the corresponding inputs while the measurements where conducted (besides a DC source to simulate the input). The measurements where conducted on P3.12 and P3.13.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table says this: -

[image]

Rephrasing what the table says: -

- A **definite** low is registered when the input is as high as 0.2\$V_{dd}\$-0.1 = 0.9 V
- A **definite** high is registered when the input is as low as 0.2\$V_{dd}\$+0.9 = 1.9 V

> While testing i discovered though, that the Controller detects a low
>   from 1.38V downwards and a high from 1.53V upwards

Yes, that doesn't sound unreasonable but, signals that feed these inputs should have high levels above 1.9 volts and low levels below 0.9 volts to guarantee successful operation. What happens between 0.9 volts and 1.9 volts has no guarantees.

Consider the standard range of TTL levels: -

[image]

On the left is the valid range for TTL input levels and these encompass the valid range of TTL output levels (on the right). There is a non-greyed-out area between about 0.7 volts and 2 volts (input) and, if a signal is at that level then the input will interpret it as either a logic 1 or a logic 0. This is the keep-out area that is needed to guarantee that gates will work properly.

Comment: You are right, but in my experience this thresholds are normally fairly accurate and not .5 volts or more off, thats whats confusing me.

Comment: They are not 0.5 volts off. The chip guarantees that it will interpret a logic "1" from between 1.9 volts and 5 volts. What would you expect a simple input pin to interpret for voltages between 0.9 volts and 1.9 volts? It's just a couple of transistors and doesn't have any facility to flag-up an invalid voltage range - it can only interpret an input voltage as 0 or 1 and, in that in-between state, it might interpret it as a 0 or a 1. Think about it.